# Difference between transform and fit_transform

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, preprocessor, kaggle

I have been doing a course on intermediate machine learning from Kaggle. In the explanation, in order to label categorical data they have used `LabelEncoder` library from sklearn.preprocessing.
[image]

Here, for training dataset they have used fit_transform and for validadtion dataset they have used only transform, why is it so?

Also, while dealing with null values, in training dataset they have used fit_transform and for validation dataset they have used transform.
[image]
So what is the difference between fit_transform and transform and what circumstances they can be used?

Answer (score 2):

fit_transform both fits the transformer to the dataset and also transforms the given data.

Transform just transforms the given dataset.

Generally you use fit_transform on the training dataset to both fit the transformer to the dataset and transform your dataset.

On your testing and validation dataset you only want to transform your dataset. This is because you want to avoid any possible data leakage. You want your testing set to have never been seen by the model you are creating in any form. One form would be influencing on how you are prepossessing the dataset.

The default replace for simple inputer which is what is used in the example is to replace with the mean. By fitting to only the train dataset you avoid any possibility that dataset from the test set influences the mean of the inputer and leaks information.

Comment: That's one reason. The other reason is, that for other transformers, like the OneHotEncoder, fitting might mean, that the number of features is fixed during the fit process and in order to apply the model later to test- or productive data, you need to maintain the same features (the same number and the same semantics). So you may not fit them after training anymore, otherwise you break your model.

Answer (score 0):

We use fit in creating machine learning models, but `fit_transform()` is used whenever we want to `fit()` the data as well as `transforming()` those values.

For example - In the case of *Label Encoding* and *Feature Scaling* we want to change or scale our values. So whenever we want to transform the values, we use `fit_transform()`.

But We do **not** use `fit_transform()` for *validation* data because of two problems:

1. Data Leakage,
2. Overfitting

We can explain those two  with a simple example-

It is like a leakage of the question paper. If we see the question paper, then there is no point in having exams. Likely If we fit test data, then the entire data is known by the model.

i.e. "Data Leakage", which may lead to  "Overfitting", which means we can do well in case of a leaked question paper, but what happens if the principal changes the question paper? Then we fail the test.